# jquery on method behaviour when element with id added later

Tags: javascript, jquery, migration, live

Here is example snippet:

```
$("#addedLater").on("click", function(){
    // code
});
```

Assume that div with id "addedLater" will be added in future.

Since the element doesn't exist while executing the above line, will jquery attach the event to document directly?

I've read that using id would be efficient while attaching event with jQuery. So I'd like to use

```
$("addedLater").on("click" function(){
  // code
});
```

instead of

```
$("#parent").on("click", ".addedLaterClass", function(){
   // code
});
```

I could not understand how does the `on` method behaves here? What would be best way to call `on` method?

Comment: Latter one is called [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), and use for dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to listen to an event directly on an element that doesn't exist yet. When you call `$(mySelector).on(/* ... */)`, jQuery is looking for all currently existing elements that match mySelector, and attaching a listener to them. It is not creating a rule that all elements that ever match mySelector will have that listener attached to them.

You can wait to call  `$("#addedLater").on("click", function(){ /* ... */});` until after #addedLater is added, or you can use event delegation by listening to the future element's parent, as you showed in your question (e.g. `$("#parent").on("click", ".addedLaterClass", function(){ /* ... */}`);

Answer (score 0):

The best way if your elements will be added dynamically is using [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$("#parent").on("click", ".addedLaterClass", function(e){
   // code
});
```

We all agree it will be way better if we could attach the event direct to element by the following instead of using event delegation:

```
$("#laterElement").on("click", function(e){
   // code
});
```

But think a little bit: It would require jQuery to have some sort of watcher or observer for every selector in every call of `$()` function. And it would be way worst in term of performance.

That's not possible becaus jQuery will only try to add the click event on the elements that matches with `$('#laterElement')` now and not in the future.

Comment: thanks lot for your time. If we try to attach event while  "laterElement" does not exists, then will jquery attach the event to the document? If write this type of code from scratch then I will follow the best practice as mentioned in the answers. Right now, Im upgrading jquery 1.4 to 1.11. So i'm trying understand where it will break, what is the best way to tackle this.

Comment: Is it fine to use id selector as second parameter with on method like below
$("#parent").on("click", "#addedLater", function(e){
   // code
});

Comment: 1 - jQuery will not automatically attach if no element match with `$()` selector. 2 - It's totally fine to use ID selector in the second parameter.